# Multiple join table in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> SELECT a.tutorial_id, a.tutorial_author, b.tutorial_count
    -> FROM tutorials_tbl a, tcount_tbl b
    -> WHERE a.tutorial_author = b.tutorial_author;
+-------------+-----------------+----------------+
| tutorial_id | tutorial_author | tutorial_count |
+-------------+-----------------+----------------+
|           1 | John Poul       |              1 |
|           3 | Sanjay          |              1 |
+-------------+-----------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
mysql>
```

This is the mysql join query tutorial on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm. But I need to join many tables. In that case.. How `WHERE` statement would look like? Please help...

Comment: Don't use the old outdated implicit joins in the `where` clause. Use an explicit `JOIN` operator. If that tutorial is advocating a join style that is over 20 years old, it might be time to find a different tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

That's a very old-fashioned way of writing joins.

New and funky way is to write it like this:

```
SELECT a.tutorial_id, a.tutorial_author, b.tutorial_count 
FROM tutorials_tbl a 
INNER JOIN tcount_tbl b ON a.tutorial_author = b.tutorial_author
```

To add more tables you just add more JOIN clauses. And since your tutorial seems a little outdated, here's the best explanation to joins I've ever seen, simple and beautiful and short: [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: +1 for link to visual explanation of `JOIN`s. It's generally easier to check charts.

Answer (score 0):

In `FROM` clause, you determine which tables to join via `JOIN` keyword, and describe common columns to pair using `ON` keyword.

```
SELECT a.tutorial_id, a.tutorial_author, b.tutorial_count 
FROM tutorials_tbl a 
  JOIN tcount_tbl b ON a.tutorial_author = b.tutorial_author
```

Or you may use `USING` since shared column names are equal:

```
SELECT a.tutorial_id, a.tutorial_author, b.tutorial_count 
FROM tutorials_tbl a 
  JOIN tcount_tbl b USING(tutorial_author)
```